# Pass message from content script to main

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

**EDIT 3: Solution/fix found**

Here's the SO thread that solved it for me: [PageMod attaching worker to same URL multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382201/pagemod-attaching-worker-to-same-url-multiple-times)

**TLDR:** If the page contains iFrames, it will attach a worker/content script to it which results in multiple content scripts attempting to run. Using `attachTo: 'top'` only attaches the script to the top level document and no iFrames.

---

I'm working on porting a simple Chrome extension I made, and I'm having a hard time with message passing for a Firefox addon. Here's what I have.

`csScript.js`

```
self.port.emit("url", getVideoUrl());

function getVideoUrl() {  
  return $('meta[itemprop=contentURL]').prop('content');
}
```

---

`main.js`

```
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: [URLs],
  exclude: [URLs],
  contentScriptFile: [data.url("jquery-2.1.1.min.js"),
                      data.url("csScript.js")],
  onAttach: function(worker) {
    worker.port.on("url", function(url) {
      var videoUrl = validateUrl(url);
      });
    }
  });
```

---

When a certain URL is hit, I want to grab an attribute value and send it back to my main.js and work with it. As it works now, I get a `message is null` error. I've read the documentation but just can't seem to understand how to pass messages.

---

Edit: Changing `onAttach` to:

```
onAttach: function(worker) {
    worker.port.on("url", function(url) {
      var videoUrl = validateUrl(url);
      });
    }
  });
```

Didn't seem to change much. All I need to do is pass one string from the content script back to my `main.js` file. However, with the code above, it's telling me that `url` is `null`. All the documentation I've looked through seems to indicate that this is how message passing works in Firefox addons.

---

<s>Edit2: After adding some log statements I noticed a couple things:</s>

1) <s>My content script is being run 10+ times when a URL is matched. I don't know why.</s> **The script was being attached to each iFrame.**

2) <s>Most of the time the URL comes back null/undefined. However, it works correctly once -- the URL is pulled from the content script and then passed correctly back to the `main.js` file. It's promptly wiped out by the content script running again, however.</s>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `pageMod` constructor, using the `attachTo: 'top'` option will attach the script to only the top level document. The content script was being attached to other iFrames and then attempting to run.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure that `getVideoUrl()` is returning a string, I'm guessing

```
$('meta[itemprop=contentURL]').prop('content')
```

does not return a string in the cases where you are getting `message is null`.

Also you had:

```
onAttach: function(worker) {
  worker.port.on("url", function(message) {
    var videoUrl = validateUrl(message.url);
    videoUrl5k = make5kUrl(videoUrl);
  });
}
```

Which I changed to:

```
onAttach: function(worker) {
  worker.port.on("url", function(url) {
    var videoUrl = validateUrl(url);
    videoUrl5k = make5kUrl(videoUrl);
  });
}
```

Perhaps that resolves the issue? since I do not see the definition for `make5kUrl`

Comment: Hi - thanks for the answer. I did a `typeof $('meta[itemprop=contentURL]').prop('content')` and it is indeed a string. I also put a `console.log` statement inside the content script and I can see that when a matching URL is loaded, the `getVideoUrl()` method is called many times (not sure why...) but it is getting in there.  Am I sending/receiving the message correctly?

Comment: please see my updated response, since I don't see how `make5kUrl` is defined I think I am missing too much.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the updated response. Those `validateUrl` and `make5kUrl` methods are just a little string manipulation. The problem is that it seems like I can't get anything back from the content script. Also, I'm noticing that the content script is run 10+ times when hitting a valid URL. Is there something that causes it to run more than once?

Comment: Solution found. Edited at the top - thanks again for the help.